# what is gora and its features?

Tags: java, hbase, gora

what is gora? what does it do for us? how it work with hbase? which features dose it have?
do you know a good essay or web page which can help me?

Comment: According to Wikipedia's disambiguation, it's "a 2004 Turkish science-fiction comedy film", but that's probably not what you had in mind ;) This might help you: https://github.com/enis/gora/wiki/design

Comment: Hibernate:RDBMS::Gora:Column Oriented databases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [its incubator page on Apache.org](http://incubator.apache.org/gora/):

> Gora is an ORM framework for column stores such as Apache HBase and Apache Cassandra with a specific focus on Hadoop.

Gora has not made any public releases yet, so you'd be a brave man to use it for a project aimed at production in the short/medium term.  However, there is quite a bit of material in the pages linked above, including a [tutorial](http://incubator.apache.org/gora/docs/current/tutorial.html) page.